# CodeIgniter, how to return multiple queries from model to controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get my model to return two queries, one for the data itself which are multiple records from the table 'Categories', and a count field, from the table 'Posts'.

I've tried alot of possible solutions, but so far none fixed it for me.

My view does work with the correct route /forum/$id, but loading the categories and a post count per category won't work.

Categories Controller:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model("Categories_model");

$results=$this->Categories_model->getCategories();

$data=array('results'=>$results);

$this->load->view('Categories_view',$results);
```

Categories Model:

```
// this works if I only want to get all the categories  
// $query=$this->db->get('Categories');
// return $query->result();

$query1 = $this->db->get('Categories');
$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM Posts");

$return array('categories' => $query1, 'count' => $query2);
```

Categories View:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($results['categories'] as $r):?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('forum'); ?>/<?=$r->CategorieId?>"><?=$r->Name?></a></td>
            <td><?=$r->rowCount?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
</tbody>
```

When I load the Categories view, I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), Filename: models/Categories_model.php

Can somebody help me with some sample code on how to do this, or a fix for my current code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using this
`$query1 = $this->db->get('Categories')->result();` 
`$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM Posts")->result();` Also include the full error message. and should be `return` not `$return`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, however I don't think it has anything to do with my queries, hence the error message I get. I think it's because it's not an array that I pass to the view?

Comment: I guess you need `=` after `$return` or may be you need `return` only without `$`

Comment: I had a really dumb mistake.. #return instead of return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return is wrong in your code remove `$` from your return type

```
$return array('categories' => $query1, 'count' => $query2);
```

it should be

```
return array('categories' => $query1, 'count' => $query2);
```

Comment: Wow that was dumb of me haha! Can you take a look into my View code? I need to also get data out of the $results['count'], but another foreach won't fix the problem cause it needs to get printed on the same table row.

Comment: @StephanB your $data array contain your array so you pass $data into view not $result   $this->load->view('Categories_view',$data);

Answer (score 1):

Running Transactions:  
To run your queries using transactions you will use the $this->db->trans_start() and $this->db->trans_complete() functions as follows:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

You can run as many queries as you want between the start/complete functions and they will all be committed or rolled back based on success or failure of any given query.
[Click here to see more](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query['categories'] = $this->db->get('Categories')->result_array();
$query['count']  = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowCount FROM Posts")->result();

return $query;
```

Try this. Not done anything great. Just used result_array() and result(). I hope they are compatible with your version of CI!!

Comment: @saty fixed the (dumb) problem. Although I can't seem to find out how to get data out of the $results['count'] (in the view), I think another foreach won't fix the problem cause it needs to get printed on the same table row.

Comment: Looking at your code the categories will be present in $categories and the count in $count. You can do print_r($categories) or print_r($count) and check it in your view!!